# Monadic guard with Either

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads

I am implementing an typechecker in Haskell. The main signature of typechecking functions is

```
judge :: Term -> StateT Context (Either String) Type
```

If the typechecker fails, it returns `lift $ Left "Something went wrong"`.

For example, a function to typecheck an if (pseudo):

```
judge (ExpIf test cons alt) =
  do
    testT <- judge test
    consT <- judge cons
    altT  <- judge alt
    guard $ consT == altT
```

Originally this code was written as follows.

```
judge (ExpIf test cons alt) =
  do
    testT <- judge test
    consT <- judge cons
    altT  <- judge alt
    if altT == consT
       then return consT
       else lift $ Left "Types for cons and alt do not match"
```

Given that, if I have a few guards, I would have too much indendation so I changed my code to use `guard`s.

I know that the return type of the `guard` expression is `()` but in the background it makes my `Either` monad fail as well by returning `Left ""`. Is there any way I could pass a string to the guard?

```
judge (ExpIf test cons alt) =
  do
    testT <- judge test
    consT <- judge cons
    altT  <- judge alt
    guard (consT == altT) "types of cons and alt should match!"
```

Comment: The only way is to define a more specific function like `guardE :: Bool -> String -> EitherT m String ()`. `guard` is essentially too polymorphic to accept a string argument - it works for any `Alternative` which makes no assumptions about being able to "throw an error from a string". You could use `Monad{Throw/Catch}` here instead of plain `Either` if you want generality.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `when`/`unless` with either `fail` or `throwError` (depending on your monad's particular implementation of these class-polymorphic functions). For example, you might write:

```
unless (consT == altT) (throwError "types of cons and alt should match")
```

Comment: The reason I chose `Either String` is that a typechecker does not really "fail". It was an issue with the semantics of throwing an error. I wanted a maltyped program to have an output as well (i.e., an error message). Sorry if I'm being difficult :)

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer I'm not sure I understood your comment. Its tone suggests it is objecting to some part of my answer (and being apologetic about it, haha), but I can't work out exactly what conflict you see between what you've said and what I wrote in my answer. Can you elaborate a bit more on what you find unsatisfactory?