# How to do control flow in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, control-flow, either

I'll give an example of what I want to do right away.

```
version1 :: IO ()
version1 =
  if boolCheck
     then case maybeCheck of
            Nothing -> putStrLn "Error: simple maybe failed"
            Just v  -> case eitherCheck of
                         Left  e -> putStrLn $ "Error: " ++ show e
                         Right w -> monadicBoolCheck v >>= \case
                                      False -> putStrLn "Error: monadic bool check failed"
                                      True  -> print "successfully doing the thing"
    else putStrLn "simple bool check failed"
```

Basically I want to "do a thing" under the condition that a number of checks turns out positive.
Whenever a single check turns out negative, I want to preserve the information about the offending check and abort the mission.
In real life those checks have different types, therefore I called them

```
boolCheck        :: Bool
maybeCheck       :: Maybe a
eitherCheck      :: Show a => Either a b
monadicBoolCheck :: Monad m => m Bool
```

Those are just examples.
Feel free to also think of monadic Maybe, `EitherT` or a a singleton list where I extract `head` and fail when it is not a singleton.

Now I am trying to improve the above implementation and the `Either` monad came into my mind, because it has the notion of aborting with an error message.

```
version2 :: IO ()
version2 = do
  result <- runEitherT $ do
    if boolCheck
       then pure ()
       else left "simple bool check failed"
    v <- case maybeCheck of
           Just x  -> pure x
           Nothing -> left "simple maybe check failed"
    w <- hoistEither . mapLeft show $ eitherCheck
    monadicBoolCheck v >>= \case
      True  -> pure ()
      False -> left  "monadic bool check failed"
  case result of
    Left  msg -> putStrLn $ "Error: " ++ msg
    Right _   -> print "successfully doing the thing"
```

While I prefer `version2`, the improvement in readability is probably marginal.
Version2 is superior when it comes to adding further checks.

**Is there an ultimately elegant way of doing this?**

What I don't like:

1) I am partly abusing the `Either` monad and what I actually do is more like a `Maybe` monad with the rolls of `Just` and `Nothing` switched in the monadic bind

2) The conversion of the checks to `Either` requires either rather verbose use of `case` or a conversion function (like `hoistEither`).

Ways of improving readability might be:

1) define helper functions to allow code like

```
v <- myMaybePairToEither "This check failed" monadicMaybePairCheck

monadicMaybePairCheck :: Monad m => m (Maybe x, y)
...
myMaybePairToEither :: String -> m (Maybe x, y) -> EitherT m e z
myMaybePairToEither _   (Just x, y)  = pure $ f x y
myMaybePairToEither msg (Nothing, _) = left msg
```

2) consistently use explicit cases, not even use `hoistEither`

3) defining my own monad to stop the `Either` abuse ... I could provide all the conversion functions along with it (if no-one has already done something like that)

4) use `maybe` and `either` where possible

5) ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `maybe`, `either`, and the `mtl` package. By the by, `eitherCheck :: Show a => Either a b`'s `Show a` constraint is probably not what you want: it lets callers choose whatever type they want as long as the type implements `Show a`. You were probably intending having `a` be a type such that callers would *only* be able to call `show` on the value. Probably!

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

newtype Error = Error String

gauntlet :: MonadError Error m => m ()
gauntlet = do
  unless boolCheck (throw "simple bool check failed")
  _ <- maybe (throw "simple maybe check failed") pure maybeCheck
  _ <- either throw pure eitherCheck
  x <- monadicBoolCheck
  unless x (throw "monadic bool check failed")
  return ()
  where
    throw = throwError . Error

version2 :: IO ()
version2 =
  putStrLn (case gauntlet of
              Left (Error e) ->
                "Error: " ++ e
              Right _ ->
                "successfully doing thing")
```

Comment: we did it / take that, other languages

Answer (score 3):

"Define helper functions" is exactly how I would handle this. The [errors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.1/docs/Control-Error-Util.html) library provides many already, with the possible exception of satisfying `Bool` functions. For those I would [just use `when`/`unless`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35026798/791604).

And of course, to the extent possible, you should promote the actions you're calling to be suitably polymorphic so that no conversion is needed.

Comment: Good point. Foor `Bool` something like `unless boolCheck $ Left "check failed" is alrady better.

Answer (score 1):

So I'd probably start by reworking your `version2` into something like

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either hiding (left, right)
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Arrow

version3 :: IO ()
version3 = eitherT onFailure onSuccess $ do
    guard boolCheck <|> fail "simple bool check failed"
    v <- hoistEither $ maybe (Left "simple maybe check failed") Right maybeCheck
    w <- hoistEither . left show $ eitherCheck
    lift (guard =<< monadicBoolCheck v) <|> fail "monadic boolcheck failed"
  where
    onFailure msg = putStrLn $ "Error: "++msg
    onSuccess _   = print "successfully doing the thing"
```

Which I find more readable, but is still a bit awkward, so if I was doing a lot
of code like this, I'd introduce some helpers:

```
version4 :: IO ()
version4 = eitherT onFailure onSuccess $ do
    failUnless "simple bool check failed" boolCheck
    v <- hoistMaybe "simple maybe check failed" maybeCheck
    w <- hoistEitherWith show eitherCheck
    failUnless "monadic boolcheck failed" =<< lift (monadicBoolCheck v)
  where
    onFailure msg = putStrLn $ "Error: "++msg
    onSuccess _   = print "successfully doing the thing"

failUnless :: Monad m => String -> Bool -> m ()
failUnless _ True = return ()
failUnless msg _ = fail msg

hoistMaybe :: Monad m => e -> Maybe a -> EitherT e m a
hoistMaybe err = hoistEither . maybe (Left err) Right

hoistEitherWith :: Monad m => (e -> e') -> Either e a -> EitherT e' m a
hoistEitherWith f = hoistEither . left f
```

Comment: I like about that, that every check turns into a one-liner and actual control flow is maximum concise.
However, when I showed code (that was somewhat like that) to others, I realized that it difficult to explain what it does and those helper functions tend to be very technical and idiosyncratic.

If, again, there was a consensus that those helper functions are the way to go, I would go for it. One might even put them into a type-classs `ToEither` and define an operator to allow code `anyWeirdTypedCheck ||! "This check failed"`

Comment: the different ways `Bool`, `Either`, `Maybe` and combined types like `(Bool, a)` are turned into Eithers might ruin the idea of having a type-class

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the full range of possible options here, check out this gist:

https://gist.github.com/rubenmoor/c390901247e4e7bb97cf

It defines several helper functions, basically combining `maybe`, `either` and such with `throwError`. and results in code like this.

```
gauntlet :: MonadError Error m => m (a, b, c)
gauntlet = do
    assertTrue boolCheck $ Error "simple bool check failed"
    v <- assertJust maybeCheck $ Error "simple maybe check failed"
    assertNothing maybeCheck' $ Error . show
    w <- assertRight eitherCheck $ Error . show
    b <- monadicBoolCheck
    assertTrue b $ Error "monadic bool check failed"
    x <- assertSingletonList list $ Error "list not singleton"
    pure (v, w, x)

version3 :: IO ()
version3 = putStrLn $
  case gauntlet of
    Left  (Error e) -> "Error: " ++ e
    Right result    -> "successfully doing thing with result"
```